# In a column if a cell is empty how to look to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do a sumifs but for one column if a cell is empty then it checks the value of the previous column.

```
    sumifs(A:A;C:C,"ccc")
```

In this example if there is no value in the column C, I want the condition to check the column B.

```
A    B    C

1    a    a

5    a    a

8    v    v

1    v    v

6    a

3    a     a
```

Here sumif(A:A;C:C;"a") does the sum of the column A if in the column C there is an "a" but if there is a blank I want to check the column B if there is an "a"

Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you post some sample data. It seems possible, if you set the condition for each column right. Probably better with `sumproduct `. But i dont want to guess, how your data might look like.

Comment: perfrom your SUMIFS on column C like you are now, then add it to a sumifs that has the same criteria as the first check but adds the criteria that C:C is blank and then set it to sum on B:B

Comment: @OverflowStacker I have updated my post with an example so you can see more clearly what I want

Comment: @ForwardEd yes but how do you add the criteria that is C:C is blank then check the column B:B instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version would be with `SUMPRODUCT`. It would also be possible with `SUMIF`'s but I'm not using it very much, so this is easier for me. :)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A3:A13)*(C3:C13="a"))+((A3:A13)*(C3:C13="")*(B3:B13="a")))
```

The part in front of `+` adds all values in column `A` when there is an "a" in column `C`. The part after `+` adds all values in column `A` when there is an "a" in column `B` and a blank cell in column `C`.

[image]

Comment: Be aware that since SUMPRODUCT performs array calculations inside its brackets you may want to avoid full column references like A:A as you will cause a lot of excess calculations on empty cells.  SUMIFS on the other hand seems not to suffer the same issues.